# order of execution for evaluating restricted picklists

Tags: apex, picklist, before-trigger, order-of-execution

I am inserting lead via soap api (formassembly form) with a `before insert` trigger that translates (invalid) incoming picklist values in various languages to valid api values.

*update - also tested via  anonymous apex so its not specific to soap api*

Test and real life are working fine, but it fails on restricted picklists.  We do not have any before save flows on leads, so per [triggers and order of execution doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.232.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm) the only step that happens prior to the before insert trigger would be

> When the request comes from other sources, such as an Apex application or a SOAP API call, Salesforce validates only the foreign keys. Before executing a trigger, Salesforce verifies that any custom foreign keys do not refer to the object itself.

If my reading of this is correct, the before insert trigger should fire and update the value and it should not fail.  My test passes if i mark the picklist as not restricted, and fails when I mark restricted with the following error, so either my interpretation is wrong (likely) or I should log a support case.  I've tried inserting lead via anon apex also, with the same result (in case it was specific to tests).

```
System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_OR_NULL_FOR_RESTRICTED_PICKLIST, Country of Election: bad value for restricted picklist field: Estados Unidos: [Country_of_Election__c]
```

For now I can mark these picklists as not restricted, but i really would prefer for them to be restricted.  If anyone can validate what the expected behavior is, that would be helpful, else I shall plead my case.

UPDATE
I dug into the debug logs, and if the picklist is marked as restricted, the before insert trigger does not fire at all.  Unlikely to prevail but will log a ticket anyways.

Debug log for restricted picklist path
[image: debug logs - failure]

Debug log for regular picklist path
[image: deubug log regular picklist path]

UPDATE 2 - Validated in a vanilla dev org with the code below

trigger

```
trigger leadBeforeInsert on Lead (before insert) {
    for(lead l : trigger.new){
        l.fruit__c = 'Apple';
    }
}
```

anon apex

```
lead l = new lead();
l.lastname = 'test';
l.company = 'test';
l.fruit__c = 'asdjfklsafjkalsf';
insert l;
```

dml error
[image: dml error]

UPDATE 3
Case #41447383 logged

Comment: I think it is independent if this is done via any API or by a process which runs internally. As you wrote, also your (unit?) test fail. Have you checked the actual API names of the picklist values? because the error messages shows the value, it tries to add (Estados Unidos) but is this really an API value?

Comment: The form submits as Estados Unidos and the trigger translates to United States.  Test and real life work fine if picklist is not set to restricted.  I'll test in a vanilla dev org to rule out anything specific to our instance.

Comment: it sure works, if not restricted, because then the picklist accepts "everything", correct? but what do you mean by "it translates"? shouldn't it just set the correct api value?

Comment: thanks, the before insert trigger takes the invalid (spanish) value and set it to a valid api value.  that is what i mean by it 'works'.   i dug into the debug logs and the before insert trigger does not fire at all - the insert on the restricted picklist blocks it.  now its just a matter of time for support to tell me its working as designed.

Comment: Interesting situation... I've started to fool around with this a bit and found out that if the value that you're putting in is an inactive option for the picklist, the trigger will execute. If you're looking at a restricted set of options that you do want to accept you could add those as inactive options (would be awful, but still...)

Comment: As a workaround, you could also validate that the value is a valid option, by looking at the available options using the describes; `Lead.Fruit__c.getDescribe().getPicklistValues()`...

Comment: thx interesting indeed.  the value set by the trigger in the proof of concept is definitely valid. adding validation in my trigger  would be a good improvement.  i have about 1500 values (many languages) so adding them as inactive is problematic - as it leaving them as unrestricted...lets see how far i can get w the gauntlet...

Comment: Would be great if you keep us updated on the case. 

Comment: @gorav did you get any update?

Comment: Nothing of substance yet, pushed back on them and waiting...

Comment: got stonewall jackson from support repeatedly pointing me at this article (https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000318237&type=1) about process builder that happens to mention order of execution.
i can accept them deciding that it is working as designed, but not from that article...i will have a call w them soon but its pretty much a lost cause at this point.

Comment: Documentation bug was logged.  They will update order of execution doc to specify that restricted picklists and foreign keys are validated prior to before triggers.

Comment: @gorav Thank you for this!